# Browser link not working VS 2013 Ultimate - seems like SignalR is not working?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, visual-studio-2013, browser-link

i did up a simple ASP.net empty project. added in some Angular scripts and index.html.

my web.config is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>

<appSettings>
  <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="true"/>
</appSettings>

<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests = "true" />
<handlers>
  <add name="Browser Link for HTML" path="*.html" verb="*"
       type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
       resourceType="File" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

i ran in debug mode and the Refresh Linked Browsers is disabled. 
I right click view source and see the injected signalr script....

```
<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
{"appName":"Internet Explorer","requestId":"b4525138f27448f4b328d597814217e0"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:4417/ecdc68cd047d49ad8af56a109101d4f7/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->
```

however when i tried running the "http://localhost:4417....." link in the browser for the signalr script file, it is not there. should i be seeing some javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

Add the tag in Web.Config

`<appSettings>
         <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false"/>
</appSettings>`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be helpful for you to add an explanation to your answer. Why should this key be set to false rather than true, as the OP currently has it? What does the key do?